# Creating a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have a User model which is designed after the Michael Hartl RoR tutorial and I am trying to create a new Teacher model. I would like the teacher to have many users but each user to have only one teacher. I created the teacher model with

```
class CreateTeachers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teachers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :phone
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and added `has_one :teacher` to user.rb. Here is the teachers.rb model

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  before_save   :downcase_email
  validates :name, presence: true, 
                 length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true, 
                    length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end
end
```

However in my teacher_test.rb test file, things get a little fuzzy. I try this

```
def setup
  @user = users(:michael)
  @user2 = users(:archer)
  @user3 = users(:lana)
  @user4 = users(:mallory)

  @teacher = Teacher.new(name: "Phred Willard",
                         email: "pwillard@test.com",
                         phone: "1234567890",
                         user_id: [@user.id, 
                                   @user2.id,
                                   @user3.id,
                                   @user4.id])
end

test "should be valid" do
  assert @uac.valid?
end
```

but that fails outright. Did I set my relationship up correctly? I obviously am not adding users correctly since the model fails a validity test. How would I add more users to that teacher? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like the teacher to have many users but each user to have only one teacher

You only need [`has_many` / `belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)...

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :teacher
end

#app/models/teacher.rb
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
end
```

You'll need to add a `teacher_id` column in your `users` table (the opposite of what you have now):

```
class UpdateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.references :teacher, index: true, foreign_key: true #-> teacher_id
    end
  end
end
```

--

The error you have is that you're calling `user_id` on `teacher`; it should be `teacher_id` on user:

```
@teacher = Teacher.new(name: "Phred Willard",
                     email: "pwillard@test.com",
                     phone: "1234567890",
                     user_ids: [@user.id, 
                               @user2.id,
                               @user3.id,
                               @user4.id])
```

This should associate `@teacher` with the defined `@users` you've listed.

You'll also want to look at [`collection_singular_ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for the `has_many` association, which is why your test is failing.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you (again). If I have a new user sign up and they want to select an existing teacher, how would I do that in the controller? I imagine something like `@teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])` and then `@teacher.user_ids.add(params[:user_id])`, but I doubt that's correct. I'm not sure how to append to a list in Rails.

Comment: What about checking if a user has a teacher? Would it be accessed by `@user.teacher`?

Comment: You could use a validation in the `user` model (`validates :teacher, presence: true`) or you could just use something like `@user.has_teacher?` and define it in the model as `def has_teacher? teacher.present? end`

Comment: I added the `has_teacher?` definition in the user model, but when testing it, I'm not getting the expected result. I tried testing with just `assert @user.has_teacher?` (`@user` comes from the setup seen in my original question), but that assertion fails. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher.rb should be

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  before_save   :downcase_email
  validates :name, presence: true, 
             length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true, 
                length: { maximum: 255 },
                format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  private

    # Converts email to all lower-case.
    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end
end
```

and user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  # rest of your code here ....
end
```

You need teacher_id column in users table.

Comment: I made these changes, but the validity test still fails. I think it's that I don't know how to add multiple users to a single teacher. Any help there?

Comment: Well, you are not creating users for a teacher in your unit test. What is `UnitAdvancementChair` in your test?

Comment: Oops, copy and pasted from the wrong file. Updated the question with the correct code I tried.